# Code snippet to display a string of characters slowly, like someone typing

Tags: javascript

I've seen some tutorials that look like someone is typing to display the lesson.

I can't remember where I've seen it, but what would be the JavaScript snippet to do that?

I'm sure it would be based upon a simple setInterval method, but I thought I would ask you in case you knew of a really good one.

Comment: This jQuery plugin sounds like what you're going for:
<http://labs.rnzmedia.co.za/typewriter.html>

Comment: Polling for JavaScript snippets seems like a better job for Google or a discussion forum than StackOverflow

Comment: I don't think so.  I mean, I'm describing the problem and people are sharing code.  I think you are being too strict.

Comment: How come people are removing their answers?  I thought they were good answers!

Comment: Not at all. There's no specific problem besides *"Here's what I want, where can I get the code"*

Comment: But the solutions have been things that I would not have thought of.

Comment: Sure, but this isn't a discussion forum. Anyway, the other answers were removed by mods because they weren't a self-contained solution to the problem, but rather were entirely dependant on external resources.

Comment: Other answers were deleted by moderator and reason is http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion

Comment: WHAT?!  Someone other than the person who posted the solution actually deleted the answer?  Oh No!  You have got to be kidding me!

Comment: Whoever deleted the answers, please stop helping.  I don't want your help.

Comment: I'm afraid your actions have cast a pall over the people that want to answer questions and will inhibit them from trying to help out any further in the future.

Comment: You and they are expected to stay within the guidelines of the site. By deleting the answers, the mods were not helping you, but rather were maintaining the integrity of StackOverflow. You may not care about this, but others do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you want?! You need a DIV with the id "typeText" in your html.

```
var theText = "myText",
progress = 0,
speed = 250;

window.setInterval(function(){
    document.getElementById("typeText").innerHTML = theText.substring(0, progress);
    progress++;
}, speed);
```

Comment: Ah, yeah.  That is nice.  And it's straight JavaScript, too.

Comment: This needs to be wrapped in a self-invoking anonymous function, right?